# PWM signal in vhdl-KIT led mechanizm

Tags: vhdl, led

I'm really new in vhdl, and I want to do some kind of KIT led mechanizm. My code should work like this- I use 18 different states for light up leds from led0 to led7, and it comes back from led7 to led0, etc. Acctually my states, and with select function did what I want, and it worked like a dream, but I wanted to turbo this mod, and add 2 other pwm signal for this code. I wrote the pwm signals but cant use those at the with case state.

It depends on current state. For example. when I'm in s5, I want to do some like this-

led5-100%
led4-60%
led3-20%

Is the problem that I have to write the pwm signals in other 2 proccesses, or what should I do with it to work?
Thanks for the help.

```
Here is my code:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;

entity knight_rider is
port(
LED0, LED1, LED2, LED3, LED4, LED5, LED6, LED7: out std_logic;
clk, reset: in std_logic);

end knight_rider; 

architecture Behavioral of knight_rider is
type state_type is (start0,s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13,s14,s15,s16);
signal current_s: state_type;
signal Counter: std_logic_vector(24 downto 0);
signal temp1_20: std_logic;
signal temp1_60: std_logic;
signal temp2_20: std_logic;
signal temp2_60: std_logic;
signal temp3_20: std_logic;
signal temp3_60: std_logic;
signal counter1_20: integer range 0 to 2048 := 0; -- counter1 for 20% bright
signal counter1_60: integer range 0 to 2048 := 0; -- counter1 for 60% bright
signal counter2_20: integer range 0 to 2048 := 0; -- counter2 for 20% bright
signal counter2_60: integer range 0 to 2048 := 0; -- counter2 for 60% bright
signal clkout60,clkout20: std_logic;
begin

knight_rider: process (clk, reset)

begin

    if (reset='1') then
     current_s <=start0;

    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    counter1_60<=counter1_60 + 1;                   --pwm for 60% briht

        if (counter1_60 = 2048) then
                temp1_60 <= '1';

                counter1_60  <= 0;

     end if;

                if temp1_60 = '1' then 
                    temp3_60 <='1';
                    temp2_60 <= '1';
                    temp1_60 <='0';
                end if;

                if temp3_60 = '1' then

                    counter2_60 <=counter2_60 + 1;
                    if (counter2_60 =1230) then
                            temp2_60 <= '0';
                            temp3_60 <='0';
                            counter2_60 <= 0;
                             clkout60<=temp2_60;
                    end if;
                end if;
    counter1_20<=counter1_20 + 1;   --pwm for 20% bright

        if (counter1_20 = 2048) then
                temp1_20 <= '1';

                counter1_20  <= 0;

            end if;

                if temp1_20 = '1' then 
                    temp3_20 <='1';
                    temp2_20 <= '1';
                    temp1_20 <='0';
                end if;

                if temp3_20 = '1' then

                    counter2_20 <=counter2_20 + 1;
                    if (counter2_20 <=410) then
                            temp2_20 <= '0';
                            temp3_20 <='0';
                            counter2_20 <= 0;
                            clkout20<=temp2_20;
                    end if;
                end if; 

        Counter<= Counter + 1;                              -- statements: From here, its actually do what I want...
        if Counter="10011000100101101000000" then       -- but with clkout20, and clkout60 something's wrong
            Counter<="0000000000000000000000000";
            case current_s is

                when start0 =>
                    current_s <=s0;

                when s0 =>
                    if (reset ='0') then
                        current_s <=s1;

                    else 
                        current_s <= start0;
                    end if;

                when s1 =>
                    if (reset = '0') then
                        current_s <=s2;
                    else 
                        current_s <= s0;
                    end if;

                when s2 =>
                    if (reset = '0') then
                        current_s <=s3;

                    else 
                        current_s <= s1;
                    end if;

                when s3 =>
                    if (reset = '0') then
                        current_s <=s4;

                    else 
                        current_s <= s2;
                    end if;

                when s4 =>
                    if (reset = '0') then
                        current_s <=s5;

                    else 
                        current_s <= s3;
                    end if;

                when s5 =>
                    if (reset = '0') then
                        current_s <=s6;

                    else 
                        current_s <= s4;
                    end if;

                when s6 =>
                    if (reset = '0') then
                        current_s <=s7;

                    else 
                        current_s <= s5;
                    end if;

                when s7 =>
                    if (reset = '0') then
                        current_s <=s8;

                    else 
                        current_s <= s6;
                    end if;

                when s8 => 
                    if (reset = '0') then 
                        current_s <=s9;
                    else
                        current_s <= s7;
                    end if; 

                when s9 => 
                    if (reset = '0') then 
                        current_s <=s10;
                    else
                        current_s <= s8;
                    end if;

                when s10 => 
                    if (reset = '0') then 
                        current_s <=s11;
                    else
                        current_s <= s9;
                    end if; 

                when s11 => 
                    if (reset = '0') then 
                        current_s <=s12;
                    else
                        current_s <= s10;
                    end if;

                when s12 => 
                    if (reset = '0') then 
                        current_s <=s13;
                    else
                        current_s <= s11;
                    end if;


                when s13 => 
                    if (reset = '0') then 
                        current_s <=s14;
                    else
                        current_s <= s12;
                    end if;

                when s14 => 
                    if (reset = '0') then 
                        current_s <=s15;
                    else
                        current_s <= s13;
                    end if;

                when s15 => 
                    if (reset = '0') then 
                        current_s <=s16;
                    else
                        current_s <= s14;
                    end if;

                when s16=> current_s <= s0;

                when others => null;
            end case;
            end if;
            end if;

end process;


                with current_s select 
                LED0 <= '1' when s0|s15,
                          'clkout60' when s1,
                          'clkout20' when s2,
                          '0' when others;

                with current_s select
                LED1 <= '1' when s1|s14,
                          'temp2_60' when s2|s15,
                          'clkout20' when s3,
                          '0' when others;

                with current_s select
                LED2 <= '1' when s2|s13,
                          'clk_out_60' when s3|s14,
                          'clk_out_20' when s4|s15,
                          '0' when others;

                with current_s select
                LED3 <= '1' when s3|s12,
                          'clk_out_60' when s4|13,
                          'clk_out_20' when s5|s14,
                          '0' when others;

                with current_s select
                LED4 <= '1' when s4|s11,
                          'clk_out_60' when s5|12,
                          'clk_out_20' when s6|s13,
                          '0' when others;

                with current_s select
                LED5 <= '1' when s5|s10,
                          'clk_out_60' when s6|s11,
                          'clk_out_20' when s7|s12,
                          '0' when others;

                with current_s select
                LED6 <= '1' when s6 | s9,
                          'clk_out_60' when s7|s10,
                          'clk_out_20' when s8|s11,
                          '0' when others;

                with current_s select
                LED7 <= '1' when s7 |s8,
                          'clk_out_60' when s9,
                          'clk_out_20' when s10,
                          '0' when others;

    end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *required* that you rewrite the code with PWM to a separate process, but
it may help on structure and readability, thus making it easier for you to get
the code to work. Some observations and suggestions:

- Create the PWM outputs in a separate process, since generation of the
  different PWM signals is not directly tied to the state update or LED drive,
  so it is probably easier for you to keep a good overview if you separate
  unrelated functionality in separate processes.
- reset signal check for '0' can be removed from the case in the knight_rider
  process, since reset is used as asynchronous reset through the first part of
  the if in that process, so when the second part takes effect, it is always
  '0'.
- Instead of the 18 states in state_type, you may consider using a
  std_logic_vector controlled as an up-down counter, since it appears you use
  the states that way.
- Make the LED as `std_logic_vector(0 to 7)` instead of separate outputs, 
  and the use the std_logic_vector state suggested above, to index the LEDs, 
  so explicit drive of each LED can be avoided in code.
- Instead of `Counter = "10011000100101101000000"` use
  `CONV_STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5000000, Counter'length)`, since this makes reading
  the value much easier.
- Instead of `Counter <= "0000000000000000000000000"` use `Counter <= (others
  => '0')` or CONV_STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0, Counter'length), for readability.
- You can significantly improve readability of your code if you use consistent
  indentation, e.g. not having the three `end case; end if; end if;` all at
  same level.  Also use only space for indent, to avoid any weird formatting
  that may occur when using tabs.
- Syntax error in `with ... select`, since clkout60 and clkout20 should not
  be 'clkout60' and 'clkout20', just plain clkout60 and clkout20.
- The clk_out_20 and clk_out_60 in `with ... select` does not exist, but that
  is probably work in progress.